# postgres SQL issue with decimal

Tags: postgresql, decimal

Hello I have an issue with line 8 something to do with decimal.

any suggestions?

```
CREATE TABLE car (
cid         CHAR(8)                     PRIMARY KEY,
reg_no      VARCHAR(9)                  NOT NULL,
colour      VARCHAR(15)                 NOT NULL,
maker       VARCHAR(20)                 NOT NULL,
model       VARCHAR(20)                 NOT NULL,
fuel_type   CHAR(6) CHECK((fuel_type IN ('petrol', 'diesel'), 
eng_size    DECIMAL(2,1)                        NOT NULL,
owner       CHAR(6)                     NOT NULL,

FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES client (client_no)
                ON DELETE CASCADE   
                                ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
);
```

Comment: And what is the **exact** error message? Btw: are you aware of the downsides of the `char` data type?

Comment: `CHECK((fuel_type IN ('petrol', 'diesel'),` is missing some close parens....

Comment: Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "DECIMAL" LINE 8: eng_size DECIMAL(2,1) NOT NULL, ^

Comment: I took out the a opening parenthesis which has resolved the problems :)
BUT I now just need to fix line 14

Comment: Always show the *exact* error message in your questions, along with your PostgreSQL version (`select version()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your '))'  were missing at the end of 8th line, and you had an extra ',' at the end before ).

This is fixed version

```
        CREATE TABLE car (
cid         CHAR(8)                     PRIMARY KEY,
reg_no      VARCHAR(9)                  NOT NULL,
colour      VARCHAR(15)                 NOT NULL,
maker       VARCHAR(20)                 NOT NULL,
model       VARCHAR(20)                 NOT NULL,
fuel_type   CHAR(6) CHECK((fuel_type IN ('petrol', 'diesel'))), 
eng_size    DECIMAL(20,15)              NOT NULL,
owner       CHAR(6)                     NOT NULL,

FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES client (client_no)
                ON DELETE CASCADE   
                                ON UPDATE CASCADE 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The line before `eng_size` field declaration missing closing parenthesis `)`

Change it from

```
fuel_type   CHAR(6) CHECK((fuel_type IN ('petrol', 'diesel'),
```

To

```
fuel_type   CHAR(6) CHECK(fuel_type IN ('petrol', 'diesel')),
```

Also, remove the `,` from the last line

```
FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES client (client_no)
                ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

See a successful fiddle here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/841fd